# Interface php results with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have quite some experience with php, but I am very new to using jQuery.

I am hoping someone can give me some example code (preferably) or point me in the right direction for which jQuery functions I need to use, essentially, what I want to do is for a user to submit a form in php and then for the results of that form submit to be displayed on the same page using jQuery (I assume).

Like I said I have very little experience with jQuery, and none doing something like this. So any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you would like the user to submit the form, have it processed (in some way) with PHP, and then have the results output/formatted with JQuery? Or that you'd like to use JQuery in processing data in a form before submitting it to a PHP script?

Comment: @imm, I mean your first question. With the processed results being outputted by jQuery.

Comment: @Neutralise, is there something specific you want to do with the results in terms of how they're displayed on the page? Can you be more specific in terms of what you ultimately want to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this answer is not really targeted at the newbie, but if you really want to dig into writing your own custom a PHP/JQuery interface you might want to try something like this:

- use ajax function name as a php pseudo function name
- implement jquery and let php echo the output.
- this can be useful if you want to only write your code in php only
- not really practical but it works some 90% of the time.

Note sure if there's any library out there that does this implementation but I do have some 
sample implementation which I use on some custom development projects, maybe you might find
some of the insights useful if you are really into writing your own code.

See the following code snippet

```
<?php
function js_start(){
  return '<script type="text/javascript">';
}

function js_add_jquery($version='1.4.2'){
  return '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/'.$version.'/jquery.min.js"></script>';
}

function js_ajax($url, $data, $success){
 return "
 $.ajax({
    url: '$url',
    data: '$data',
    success: $success
  });";
}


function js_end(){
  return '</script>';
}


//Example usage:
// where success is behaviour you want executed on success
$success =
"function(data) {
  $('#page').html(data);
}";

echo js_add_jquery(); // default version 1.4.2 is used here
echo js_start();
echo js_ajax('test.php', 'name=John&surname=Doe', $success);
echo js_end();
?>
```

Comment: My question was quite ambiguous, but ultimately this is the kind of thing I was hoping to see. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it was ambiguous.  And no, this is NOT the kind of thing you should be hoping to see.  The whole REASON for a framework like jQuery is to AVOID this kind of coding style!  If you're interested in books, I'd recommend "jQuery in Action, 2nd Ed", Bibeault & Katz.  IMHO .. PSM

Comment: Like I said initially, its not practical but I find it useful when you need to keep your code native in PHP only. One could argue against this kinds on programming methods, but fact remains, for ease of use and re-usability of code, you will find it quite frustrating to develop a system in PHP and have to write additional javascript code. [Rule of thumb] If you are developing in native codes, stick to native coding! This is why several PHP frameworks exists to allow you to code only in PHP- CakePHP, Symfony to name but a few!

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out the jQuery form plugin.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

The site has loads of examples too.

Comment: excellent suggestion!  And a great way for a beginner to "dip their toes" into jQuery!
@Neutralize: the "classic" technique in PHP is a) create the form in PHP b) POST back to the 
server (perhaps validate locally with a little Javascript first), then c) create a new HTML 
page in PHP as the response.  jQuery, in contrast, modifies the INITIAL page; it also "phones
home" to the server (with Ajax).

Answer (score 0):

You could place a function on a button that checks for values in input fields and then writes them out in another area.

Your question is a bit ambiguous.

Resources:
http://api.jquery.com/val/